# Wordpress, where do my posts go?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have converted my html/css to wordpress by following a very simple guide. 
On my WP-site, I would like to have a simple "blog-page", a page where i can update the visitors about events and so on. I created a page called events but how do I make my posts appear on this particular page?

When i create a new post I can click "view post" to see it but i does not show i on my events-page. In fact, I have no idea where it ends up? Its like creating a new page except for that it does not add to the menu?

Comment: do you mean to display your blog posts into the events page?

Comment: Yes, thats what i want. I assume that I can choose on what page I want the posts to appear?

Comment: take a look on the answer that helps you to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Settings, Reading.

Choose 'Front page displays *a static page*' and select the page you want as your front page. 
On the next line 'posts page' select the page you named 'Events'.

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! I think you are right but I also think that before I can do that I have to add som php-code to my event-template. Right now i only have the get_header and get_footer..

Comment: I don't think you need a custom template, you could just use your default template.

Answer (score 1):

*"how do I make my posts appear on this particular page"*

For this you have to create a [custom template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) for your blog section, and select that template during page creation(events) for particular page. That's it.

Follow this link to know how to implement it. http://www.expand2web.com/blog/custom-page-template-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have already created my template, I then created a new page i wordpress and used that template. However, when I use create post on the dashboard it doesnt show up on the right place.
In the "create post"-section i can create a post and view it, but thats it.

Comment: what is the name of your custom template?

Comment: its "page-blog.php" ( /* Template name: blog page */

Comment: `/* Template Name: blog page */`